# Accessing NSManagedObject fields with KVC/valueForKey vs properties - which is better?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, coding-style

Writing my first app with CoreData.  The book I'm using to guide me has code like this:

```
// 'Person' is my managed object class
Person *newPerson = [NSEntityDescription
  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person"
  inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

[newPerson setValue:nameField.text forKey:@"name"];
```

The book says that using the property style, e.g.

```
newPerson.name = nameField.text;
```

also works, but that "it is very common to see Core Data code use the KVC Approach"

To me, I can't see one reason to use the KVC approach; magic strings just beg for runtime errors and it's a lot more typing.

That being said, I'd like to learn my habits *now* regarding the "iPhone Way" of doing things.

Is there a difference in these approaches and, if most people use the first, KVC, approach…why?

Comment: The PragProg book by Dudney and Adamson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most people do not use the KVC approach I have seen; I do not, for the reasons you describe.

To save your sanity, use Mogenerator to build your accessors:

http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/

It's a command line tool that generates proxy objects that you can use to fetch CoreData objects, with some convenience methods - but even better, some category overlays that you can add your own methods to that will not be destroyed when you re-generate classes from your data model.

XCode can also generate data objects from your model but the classes are more simple (just accessors), and mogenerator is I think easier to use repeatedly (which is important since you will tend to change the model a lot over time).  Perhaps the next XCode will be better in that regard.

I usually generate all data model classes into a subdirectory under Classes called "DataObjects" - then you can just re-add that whole directory every time you regenerate classes from the data model that leads to new classes being created (when you have new entities).  A sample command line run looks like:

```
 mogenerator -m ../MyProject.xcdatamodeld/MyProject-v1.xcdatamodel
```

which will generate classes into the current directory from the given data model (in that case I have a versioned model with just the first version).

Comment: Using KVC for setting properties on managed objects is quite useful. For example, you can create a category on `NSManagedObject` where you pass a JSON dictionary and the MO properties will be automagically populated with the values from the dictionary. Or, create a category that extends `setValue:forKey`, but which only sets the new value if it differs from the old value. That one is essential if you have `NSFetchedResultsControllers` that are watching for data changes and you don't want your tableView to be constantly animating bogus changes in/out.

Comment: You can create the same dictionary input category using the mogen generated classes, the mogen classes just extend what you can do with a managed object... you could also adjust the mogen templates to add the comparison check before setting a new value (though personally I would think the potential overhead from every insert or read from storage doing that check would be more than you would save from occasionally setting duplicate values)

Answer (score 1):

Properties will result in a fractional performance increase over direct KVC usage.  However KVC does have its uses especially when working with a `keyPath` as opposed to just a `key`.

KVC is also useful when you are discovering or dynamically accessing values on an object.

For every day use, Kendall is definitely right, use mogenerator and utilize properties.  Easier to code, easier to maintain, etc. However KVC definitely has its place and is extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

`name` is a property of NSEntityDescription, so `newPerson.name` is fine.

But when you add a custom property to your custom entity, it is only known about at runtime - so `newPerson.favouriteRestaurant` will trigger a compile time warning, even though it's fine.

This is annoying.

One way to get rid of it is to use

```
[newPerson setValue:@"Crazy Maria's" forKey:@"favouriteRestaurant"]
```

This can be a useful way to stop the compiler nagging in several other scenarios when you are gong to use runtime magic.

Comment: You can add a property `favouriteRestaurant` in `@interface` to shut up the compiler, if you want.

Comment: You mean if you add a custom class for your entity?